# How to open file type with Notepad Legacy in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, notepad

I installed Windows 11 on my PC but excluded the new **UWP Notepad** app.

Though it supports dark theme, it has ridiculously varied-spaced characters (same words on different lines having different widths).

I decided to use **Legacy Notepad** to open files but cannot find a way to set the app as the default to open these files, as *Notepad* is not showed in the **Open With dialog**.

Open the files with the *Notepad.exe* in **Windows**, **system32**, or other paths show the error *"The program you have selected cannot be associated with this file type. Please choose another program."*

I have tried using *cmd* `assoc .json=txtfile` or `assoc .json=txtfilelegacy` but none work, too.

Comment: Where did you get the old notepad.exe from?

Comment: Optional features -> Add a feature -> Notepad (system)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

After diving into the change made by the tool, I found that the **String** `NoOpenWith` (no data) is removed from the **Registry** key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\Applications\notepad.exe
```

---

**Old answer:**

OK so I found the solution.

Download **OpenWithView** by *Nirsoft*.

*Legacy Notepad* will be listed on the tool.

Right click the app and choose **Enable Selected Items** and you're all set.

Now *Notepad* will show in the *Open with Dialog*.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution

Comment: Thanks for this. I decided to skip the middleman and went straight to registry. Removing `NoOpenWith` let's me set notepad as default text editor. I don't understand why this registry setting even exists and why is it set on the basic text editor...

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution without having to download third party software.

**To use old notepad,paste this code in notepad and save as as a *.reg file and run it:**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;Restore Old Classic Notepad on Windows 11
;Created by Ramesh Srinivasan for Winhelponline.com
;Created on May 6, 2022; Revised on May 12, 2022.

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad.exe]
"NoOpenWith"=-

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\notepad.exe]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfilelegacy\DefaultIcon]
@="imageres.dll,-102"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfilelegacy\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe \"%1\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe]
"UseFilter"=dword:00000000
```

**To undo the changes and use the notepad app again paste this code in notepad, save as a *.reg file and run it:**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad.exe]
"NoOpenWith"=""

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfilelegacy\DefaultIcon]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfilelegacy\shell\open]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe]
"UseFilter"=dword:00000001
```

I found this solution here:
https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/restore-old-classic-notepad-windows/

Comment: Cool! The site could have saved my last couple of days.

Comment: Ricardo, just posting a link cannot be considered as an answer for the reasons outlined by Toto above. Please follow his advice! Thank you.

Comment: Posting a link to the source is not a problem.  He clearly spelled out how to solve the problem without said link.  He was merely pointing out where the source material came from.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Please check the edit history.

Comment: AHA!  OK.. I get it.  Danke Thanks Gracias Amigo!

Answer (score 0):

Curiously, although you cannot "Open (a .srt file) With (Notepad)", you CAN run Notepad, then Open the desired .srt file!!! It could be that some .srt files have embedded characters (e.g., musical notations) that Notepad cannot display, but, you'd think it would just display garbage, instead, and allow the remaining characters - - time and plain text - - to display properly.

Or, use Wordpad instead (on my machine, it's located at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories).

Answer (score -2):

This is the answer but someone voted it down and I dont have enough rep as this is a new account to upvote it so I'm posting it again.  THANK YOU to the person above who posted this, it works, it's easy and it should NOT be voted down.

I found another solution without having to download third party software.

*To use old notepad,paste this code in notepad and save as as a .reg file and run it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;Restore Old Classic Notepad on Windows 11
;Created by Ramesh Srinivasan for Winhelponline.com
;Created on May 6, 2022; Revised on May 12, 2022.

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad.exe]
"NoOpenWith"=-

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\notepad.exe]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfilelegacy\DefaultIcon]
@="imageres.dll,-102"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfilelegacy\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe \"%1\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe]
"UseFilter"=dword:00000000
```

*To undo the changes and use the notepad app again paste this code in notepad, save as a .reg file and run it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad.exe]
"NoOpenWith"=""

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfilelegacy\DefaultIcon]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfilelegacy\shell\open]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe]
"UseFilter"=dword:00000001
```

I found this solution here: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/restore-old-classic-notepad-windows/
Share
Edit
Follow
edited Jun 8 at 12:17

Comment: Am I missing something?  Is this not a repost of the SAME EXACT answer by @Ricardo_Bohner that got voted down?  I am not picking at the answer itself but re-posting the same answer doesn't make sense to me.